# How would I output this array of strings?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

Say I had an array of strings...

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"red", @"blue", @"green", @"yellow", nil]
```

how would I achieve an output like this...?

> red is a color
>   blue is a color
>   green is a color
>   yellow is a color

Thanks!

Comment: What language do you want it in?

Comment: Where do you want this output to go?  To a file, to stdout, to stderr?

Answer (score 7):

```
NSArray *colors = ...;
for (NSString *color in colors) {
  NSLog(@"%@ is a color", color);
}
```

Comment: Don't use NSLog() for ordinary string output.  It prepends a lot of information that the question doesn't ask for.

Comment: Well i'm using Obj c in xcode, I need the output to be in NSString format so that i can display the list of results in a textView

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *initializedNSArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"red", 
                                                         @"blue", 
                                                         @"green", 
                                                         @"yellow", 
                                                         nil]
for( int i=0; i<4; ++i )
    NSLog(@"%@ is a color \n", [initializedNSArray objectAtIndex: i];
                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  to array it is earlier initialized to
```